# Should a question be migrated if it's going to be closed anyway?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, migration

There's [a question about Fourier series](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5391/derivation-of-fourier-series) on physics.SE that seems purely mathematical in nature - at least, it's definitely off-topic on the physics site, and seems like it would be on topic here. But the topic might already covered by other existing questions, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/proving-a-fourier-series-identity) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/fourier-transform-for-dummies). So I figured I'd ask:

1. Would this question from physics.SE be appropriate at math.SE?
2. If not, should I migrate it anyway and flag it to be closed here?

Comment: Dear David, the question is on topic, but extremely vague.

Comment: @Akhil: yeah, that's what I thought too. Does that affect whether it should be migrated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reason not to migrate, assuming the *essential* rule of "is it on-topic for the target site?" has been decided:

> If the question is of very low quality, do not migrate it.

This is effectively like throwing trash on your neighbor's front lawn. Be a good neighbor! :)

Answer (score 4):

Without looking at any of the linked questions, supposing that there is a question on some other site that is off topic there and a more appropriate fit here, even if it would end up closed as a duplicate, it's worth migrating.  The migration creates the cross-link from the original question to the migrated question here; the closed-as-duplicate creates a link from the migrated version here to the pre-existing question that covers the same content.  In all that, the original off-topic question ends up connected to an existing question with (hopefully) an appropriate answer.